# Unit testing in python - How to test the data types in a dataframe returned by using `read_sql_query` are expected?

Tags: python, mysql, pandas, unit-testing, types

I'm using `pandas.read_sql_query()` to read some data from the database, SOMETHING LIKE:

```
def get_data(mysql_engine) -> DataFrame:
    query = """SELECId FROM xxx.xxx"""
    dtypes = {
        "Id": 'Int64'
    }
    dataframe = pd.read_sql_query(universe_query, mysql_engine, dtype=dtypes)

    return dataframe
```

How can I write unit tests to validate the datatypes are expected?

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like:

```
...

dtypes = {
        "Id": np.int64
    }

...

df_dtypes = {col: dtype.type for col, dtype in dataframe.dtypes.to_dict().items()}

assert df_dtypes === dtypes
```

Note that you have to use `np.*` datatypes in your `dtypes` variable for the above to work.